# How to make a delicious cold coffee from ground coffee?

Tags: ground-coffee, milk, iced-coffee

I am new to coffee drinking and I just checked what I am drinking till now is instant coffee. So, I was wondering is it possible to make cold coffee? Not cold brew, just a normal cold coffee with ground coffee? And, how to make it an amazing one?

Answer (score 3):

What you have mentioning is widely known as iced-coffee.

The most widely adopted method is to brew any type of coffee: filter, drip or french-press. Then, adding ice cubes in a cup and pour the coffee to fill the cup. After that, you mix it to homogenize the temperature, add milk and sugar if desired.

Another method is known as Japanese brew. In that method, you prepare an ice cube filled cup beforehand. Then, pull your shot of espresso on top of ice. (Optionally, filter/drip on top of ice.) This method is known to preserve aromas better than the previous.

Comment: So is making ice coffee from ground coffee simple or can you suggest me any site or video for it.

Comment: You can just search youtube, I assume. This is the first one I encounter: [French-press iced coffee](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eb5c04-ygpQ). Or [filtered Japanese brew](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DTpmxf8qdzs).

Answer (score 1):

May i offer a nice way to do your cold coffee for great flaour?

If you do pour over for your ground coffee (like a v60) try a 60/40 ratio of hot water to ice
[To quote shamelessly from this recipe at squaremile](http://www.squaremileblog.com/2018/07/05/cold-brew-vs-iced-coffee-helpful-hints-and-tips/)

> We use a 60/40 ratio of hot water to ice. For example, if you’re making a 500ml brew, your recipe will be 32.5g of coffee, 300g of hot water and 200g of ice. For best results, use filtered water with a low mineral content.

Ice goes in vessel; remaining hot water poured onto grounds as usual, and voila - stir coffee after to make sure ice is melted and - mmm mm good.

Enjoy.
mc

Answer (score 0):

The other option you may consider is cold brew.  I personally favor this as it is less bitter and has more of the coffee flavor.  Works great with light roasts.  The downside is that it takes hours to brew.  There are all kinds of gadgets for this including some that can brew in under 20 minutes but if you have a french press and a refrigerator you are ready to go.  Just throw the grounds and water in the press and cover it with saran wrap or something.  Throw it in the fridge overnight and in the morning press the grounds and enjoy a delicious cold brewed cup of coffee.